# Rewrite Specific URL PHP htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a custom php file at the following url

```
http://example.com/index.php?route=product/overview&pid=85
```

and i want only this URL to rewrite like as below

```
http://example.com/overview/85
```

No other URLs shall be affected in the website. Is that possible using htaccess to rewrite only one specific URL.

I tried like below

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/$ /product/overview&pid=?$1 [L]
```

But it is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?route=product/$1&pid=$2 [L]
```

Comment: but with this all my URLs starting with product will be affected

Comment: No, they wont be affected because We are using RewriteConds to exclude them

Comment: With this my admin folder is not working now. getting 404 there, My Admin folder says `http://example.com/admin` and then i tried not to rewrite admin as `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/admin/` but even then admin section stopped working

Comment: Is your htaccess in root folder?

Comment: Just a point that i am using Opencart framework if that can affect any rewrite? should i paste my htaceess?

Comment: It worked with below rule `RewriteRule ^product/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?route=product/$1&pid=$2 [L]`